# Flutter: RenderPhysicalModel object was given an infinite size during layout

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am making a SignUp Screen, at first I had like no problems as when I run the code but the **Bottom OverFlow by some pixels** as I haven't inserted ScrollView or ListView, but as I add the ScrollView or ListView over my Scaffold I get the error like:
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderPhysicalModel object was given an infinite size during layout.
The relevant error-causing widget was
Scaffold
lib\screens\home.dart:22
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Here's my code:

```
Widget buildSignInScreen(){
  return SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 40),
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topCenter,
            colors: [
              Colors.deepPurple.shade900,
              Colors.deepPurple.shade800,
              Colors.deepPurple.shade400,
            ]
          )
        ),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: 70,),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("Login",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 30 ),),
                  SizedBox(height: 10,),
                  Text("Welcome Back",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 30 ),),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(50),topRight: Radius.circular(50),)
                  ),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            boxShadow: [BoxShadow(
                              color: Color.fromARGB(220, 90, 30, 10),
                              blurRadius: 20,
                              offset: Offset(0,10),
                            )]
                          ),
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade200))
                                ),
                                child: TextField(
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    hintText: "Phone Number",
                                    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                                    border: InputBorder.none,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade200))
                                ),
                                child: TextField(
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    hintText: "Password",
                                    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                                    border: InputBorder.none,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 40,),
                        Text("Forget Password",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),),
                        SizedBox(height: 40,),
                        Container(
                          height: 50,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                            color: Colors.deepPurple[900],
                          ),
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text("Login",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 18,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 60,),
                         Text("Continue with social media",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey,),),
                        SizedBox(height: 20,),
                        Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Expanded(
                              child: Container(
                                height: 50,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                                ),
                                child: Center(
                                  child: Text("Twitter",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: 30,),
                            Expanded(
                              child: Container(
                                height: 50,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                                  color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                                ),
                                child: Center(
                                  child: Text("Skype",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: 30,),
                          ],
                        )
                          ],
                        ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the Expanded widget from the `Column` and load SingleChildScrollView to the parent of `Container` not `Scaffold`. Please find the code snippets below,

```dart
Widget buildSignInScreen() {
  return Scaffold(
    body: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 40),
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(begin: Alignment.topCenter, colors: [
          Colors.deepPurple.shade900,
          Colors.deepPurple.shade800,
          Colors.deepPurple.shade400,
        ])),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 70,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "Login",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Welcome Back",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(50),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(50),
                  )),
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                              color: Color.fromARGB(220, 90, 30, 10),
                              blurRadius: 20,
                              offset: Offset(0, 10),
                            )
                          ]),
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border(
                                    bottom: BorderSide(
                                        color: Colors.grey.shade200))),
                            child: TextField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                hintText: "Phone Number",
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                                border: InputBorder.none,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border(
                                    bottom: BorderSide(
                                        color: Colors.grey.shade200))),
                            child: TextField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                hintText: "Password",
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                                border: InputBorder.none,
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 40,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Forget Password",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 40,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 50,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                        color: Colors.deepPurple[900],
                      ),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          "Login",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 18,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 60,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Continue with social media",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                            height: 50,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                              color: Colors.blueAccent,
                            ),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                "Twitter",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 30,
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                            height: 50,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                              color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                            ),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                "Skype",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 30,
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

[image]